# Scrape content in json format - Python

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape pages like [this](https://www.laperla.com/fr/en/cfiplm000566-bgw532.html) using Python 3.5. I have scraped its content using BeautifulSoup. I have a problem in scraping the number of sizes.  In this specific page the number of sizes is 9 (FR 80 A,FR 80 B,FR 80 C etc). I suppose this information is in json format. I am trying to use json package but I can't find the 'start' and 'end'.
My code looks like this:

```
import requests
import json

page = requests.get('https://www.laperla.com/fr/en/cfiplm000566-bgw532.html')
content = page.text    
start = content.find('spConfig') + ...
end = ...    
data = json.loads(content[start:end])
sizes = data['attributes']['179']['options']
print(len(sizes))
```

The correct output should be '9', since there are 9 sizes. I don't want to use selenium or such packages. So, which is the correct 'start' and 'end'? Is there a better way to scrape this data than what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 . Iterate all `script` tags and search target json

2 . Use `regex` to grab `start` and `end`

3 . Use `json` module

```
for i in soup.select('script'):
    if 'Product.Config' in str(i):
        data = re.search(r'(?is)(Product\.Config\()(.*?)(\))',str(i)).group(2)

json_data = json.loads(data)
print(len(json_data['attributes']['179']['options']))
9
```